# Display content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Quick question, how to display search result on 'page-result' div,  in another page:

```
document.getElementById( 'page-result' ).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

any idea?!

Comment: need more details , not getting you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jquery?

```
$('#page-result').html( xmlhttp.responseText);
```

If you need to do in in another window just open it

```
var newWindow = window.open( 'some params');
$(newWindow.document).find('#page-result')
```

Comment: it s must be something similiar to this, but it s not working. Its not put result search on this new page.

Comment: @NasanErt now that i understand what your really need, i've edited my anwser. That should work for you.